# Handling Enum values from different enums that implement a certain interface in a switch/case

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement

I have an empty interface `Units` that I'm using to tag different `enums` so I know that they hold different units (e.g. I have an `enum TemperatureUnits implements Units{}` that stores Fahrenheit, Celsius, etc., then I have a `DistanceUnits` that holds Meters, Feet, etc.

I want to do different things in a switch/case based on which `enum` value is passed to a method.  I want it to accept a value from any `enum` that implements `Units`.  The problem is that, since the `enums` are actually different classes, I have to use the qualified name of the value in the switch/case.  My code looks something like this:

```
     public static void foo(Units units){ //units has to be an enum that implements Units

        switch (units){
            case TemperatureUnits.FAHRENHEIT: //I can't say just FAHRENHEIT, because Units itself doesn't 
                //have a FAHRENHEIT value, but it won't let me say TemperatureUnits.FAHRENHEIT because it won't let use
                // qualified enum values as cases.
                //Do stuff
                break;
            case DistanceUnits.METERS:
                //Do other stuff
                break;
            //...etc
```

How would I have a switch/case statement that can use values from different `enums`?

Edit: My `Units` interface is just:

```
public interface Units{
    String getLabel();
}
```

Comment: Use polymorphism instead of a giant switch case, that would become incorrect as soon as a new enum constant or enum class is defined. Add a method in Units, override it in all the enums, and call it instead of executing the switch block. i.e. use units.foo() instead of foo(units). The interface should be named `Unit`, BTW: CELSIUS_DEGREE is a Unit, not a Units.

Comment: This looks like a situation in which you're defining a *tagged class*, i.e. the behavior of the class changes importantly depending on the value of some tag (Temperature, Distance, etc.)  In this case, your best, most elegant, and most robust solution (as JB has mentioned) is to develop a class hierarchy (eg. TemperatureUnits is a subclass of Units).  Otherwise, your code can end up looking very ugly if you try to do it all with one big class (or enum).  The specific behavior you want can be easily defined by the subclasses.

Comment: Why do you want to have a base enum for totally unrelated things like temperature, distance, and so on?

Comment: @Robert: If he really wanted to go at this with enums, he could probably get a nice looking solution with nested enums, but I agree that the present enum is too much like a *tagged-class* antipattern.

Comment: @Robert Because I'm going to be using them for related applications.  The program needs a unit and what kind of unit it is (e.g. meters = distance, Celsius = temperature), but should be able to perform the same operations on any unit of any type; thus, they should have a common superclass/interface/whatever

Comment: @Caketray Hm... smells a bit like Speculative Generality to me. Do you have any code in the base enum that the derived ones share? Do you ever want to pass an instance of the base enum or don't you always really need to specify a particular derived enum? Or, asking differently: will you have a method that accepts kilograms and degrees celsius interchangeably?

Comment: @Robert, yes, it should accept either, but still know what type they are

Comment: @Caketray Ok, now I am curious. Can you give an example of a method that needs to be able to deal with any unit?

Comment: @Robert I'm making a (supposed to be) simple unit conversion program. I had an idea where I would have a method that could take any two units of the same type and convert from one to the other. At this point, I'm thinking it'll probably be easier if I just use multiple methods

Comment: Ok, but then why the base enum? If you have `convert(Unit)`, you can pass any nonsense unit, e.g, convert meters to seconds, and the compiler won't complain.

Comment: @Robert The idea was that it would have a check. Within the case statements would be checks to make sure that you're converting to something valid. That might be a stupid way to do it; I'm pretty new to java

Answer (score 3):

That is not allowed by the Java Language specification.

[14.11. The switch Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11) says that

> The type of the Expression must be char, byte, short, int, Character, Byte, Short, Integer, String, or an enum type ([§8.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9)), or a compile-time error occurs.

Here, the *Expression* is the value you are switching on (`switch(expression)`). In your case, the type of the expression is `Units` which is an interface and not an `enum`.

Next to that

> Every case label has a case constant, which is either a constant expression or the name of an enum constant.

[Enum *constants*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.1) are not qualified by the enum type, so you cannot mix different enum type constants in a switch.

A possible solution for you would be to implement it like this:

```
interface Unit {
    void doSomething();
}

enum A implements Unit {
    A_ONE,
    A_TWO,
    A_THREE {
       void doSomething() {
           // implement it in a way specific for A_THREE
       }
    };

   void doSomething() {
       // implement it in a generic way for A
   }
}
```

That way every enum that implements `Unit` can - and must - have the "handling logic" encapsulated inside it and if you have any special enum constants - they can implement the special logic themselves. Naturally, sometimes each enum constant can have a specific implementation and there will not be one generic on the enum class level.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `instanceof` operator to determine which `enum` was passed in, & then `switch` based on the appropriate `enum`:

```
public static void foo(Units units) {
    if(units instanceof DistanceUnits) {
        DistanceUnits d = (DistanceUnits) units; // METERS, INCHES...

        switch (d) {
            case METERS:
                // code
                break;
            case INCHES:
                // code
                break;
        }
    }
    else if(units instanceof TemperatureUnits) {
        TemperatureUnits t = (TemperatureUnits) units; // FAHRENHEIT, CELSIUS

        switch (t) {
            case FAHRENHEIT:
                // code
                break;
            case CELSIUS:
                // code
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Considering this:

```
enum DistanceUnits implements Units {
    METERS, INCHES
}

enum TemperatureUnits implements Units {
    FAHRENHEIT, CELSIUS
}

public interface Units {
    // some code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might suit your use case:

```
/** Defines all supported unit types */
public enum UnitType {
    Distance,
    Temperature,
    Volume
};

/** Defines all units (of all supported unit types) */
public enum Units {

    FEET(UnitType.Distance),
    METERS(UnitType.Distance),

    FAHRENHEIT(UnitType.Temperature),
    CELSIUS(UnitType.Temperature),

    GALLONS(UnitType.Volume),
    LITERS(UnitType.Volume);

    private final UnitType type;

    Units(UnitType type) {
        this.type = type;
    };

    public UnitType getType() {
        return type;
    }

}

// In some class
...
public static void foo(Units units) {
    switch (units) {
        case FAHRENHEIT:
            // ...
            break;
        case METERS:
            // ...
            break;
        case GALLONS:
            // ...
            break;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot one of these `*/`, btw

Comment: Thanks. That comment is now finished off.